# Microsoft 365/Exchange Online - Outlook rule "Have server reply using message..." not working when recipient is on exchange online

Tags: exchange, outlook, exchangeonline

I have a user that wants an automatic reply being sent back only to certain people (outside the org) with his outlook client.

I have managed to configure the outlook rule "have server reply using message" and created a template. This seems to work fine when sender don't have an exchange online mailbox, but not when the sender is on exchange online as well.

I know that I can add an autoreply with a template, but this works only when the user is running outlook, I need it to be server side. Can anyone help me out with this one?

Comment: Open a support case in your Office 365 tenant. It's free of charge. That's the quickest way to get it resolved.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely do that!

Comment: Would you mind to mark the helpful reply as a best answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I opened a support case in my Microsoft 365 Tenant. Due to the limitations in OOF I am forced to go with the outlook rule "have server reply using message". As of now Microsoft does not have a proper way to make this work nor a workaround.

Comment: Yes, i think "have server reply using message " is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, OOF should work properly whether the outlook client is online or offline.
When the Out of Office Assistant is enabled, only one reply is sent to each sender, even if you receive multiple messages from that person.

You could add the external users as contacts and set the OOF only reply the contacts.
[image]

If you would like to have a reply sent for every message, use Rules instead of the Out of Office Assistant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the function of OOF. Problem with OOF is that I only have two options to configure automatic replies - inside my org and both, but not only outside the org. Also I want to be able to get the auto-reply triggered with every email that is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create a rule in outlook to trigger with every emails.
Check below screenshot, and create a similar rule for yourself.
[image]

Comment: Did the issue get resolved?
I'd appreciate it if you choose the most helpful post above and mark it as the best answer, this will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well. Thanks!